# PFQuery inside cellForRowAtIndexPath run multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm using Parse and I'm building social networking app, user can comment on a post and another users could like that post just like Facebook App.

This is a piece of my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Get all comments
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Comment")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { comments, error in
        if error == nil {
            self.comments = comments
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let commentForThisRow = self.comments[indexPath.row] // contains array of PFObject

    // Get all activities which like this comment
    var likeQuery = PFQuery(className: "Activity")
    likeQuery.whereKey(kSFActivityType, equalTo: kSFActivityTypeLike)
    likeQuery.whereKey(kFSActivityComment, equalTo: commentForThisRow)
    likeQuery.findObjectsInBackground { 
        // Store array of users who like this comment to the cell
    }
}
```

The problem is, because cell for row at indexpath called everytime user scrolls the tableView, it makes the likeQuery run everytime and do request. 

How to make the likeQuery request only run one time?

Comment: It might be better form to load the users who liked the comment after some stimulus (for example tapping the number of likes). Otherwise you have to store an array of arrays

Comment: @milesper It can be, but I still need the number of likes though, which means I need to do a request to get the number of likes for every row.

Comment: That's the sort of thing you might want to store separately as a "likes" property that you increment or decrement at the same time as when you change the array of people who liked it

Comment: Otherwise you could get a number of likes by running a PFQuery for each comment, getting the number of likes, and saving that number to an array in viewDidLoad

Comment: Hi @Edward Anthony did you find a solution? I'm struggling with the same problem =/